# Can I run After Effects in Ubuntu?

Tags: video

Well guys, I'm wanting to change the operating system, leave the windows and jump right in linux, and I went back and found nearly all programs, or programs similar to the same function in Ubuntu.

Has only one I need and can not find any way, I need a video editor like After Effects of adobe. So I wonder if a program with the same power of AE exist or if there is any way to run the AE (Aflter Effects) on Ubuntu?

Comment: [Kdenlive](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdenlive/) works OK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with Jahshaka. Here's a link about it: http://www.taringa.net/posts/linux/3240940/Jahshaka---After-Effects-de-Linux.html
It's in Spanish so I think you'll understand (due to the fact that you speak portuguese).

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to run it under Wine, although the versions starting from 8 to 11 are marked as Garbage (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=648).

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta me ajudou muito